# Processing text in Ruby from row

Tags: ruby, csv, loops

I have a csv which I would like to process instances of a row[report] based on the input of another row[number].

```
Report,Number,Name,Date
INC AMT %,12345678,ACME INC,10/30/2012
INC AMT %,12345678,ACME INC,10/31/2012
OUT AMT %,12345678,ACME INC,10/31/2012
# shortened for brevity
```

My code block looks like this:

```
require 'CSV'

module AlertHash
  @alert_hash = {}
  CSV.foreach("alerts.csv") do |row|
    report, number = row
    next if number == "Number"
    @alert_hash[number] = report
  end

  def self.report(number)
  @alert_hash[number]
  end

end

puts "Alert: " + AlertHash.report("12345678")
# OUTPUT => Alert: OUT AMT %
# DESIRED OUTPUT => Alert: INC AMT %, OUT AMT %
```

I've been able to process the last [report]stack of each number. However, my desired output would be to capture **ALL** reports for a given row[number].  Can someone give me some pointers on how this could be done?  Maybe I'm approaching this problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
@alert_hash[number] = report
```

will overwrite any previous value for any given number index, so you only retain the last one. That's why you get the `OUT` value only. If you want to collect all lines for a given number, use an array:

```
@alert_hash[number] ||= [] # initialize array if required
@alert_hash[number] << report # add value
```

and then concatenate them in your `report` method:

```
@alert_hash[number].join(", ")
```

This will give you:

```
Alert: INC AMT %, INC AMT %, OUT AMT %
```

Not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but this explains your code's current behaviour.

Comment: @Thilo, thanks for explaining why I was not able to collect all elements from a row.  I'm a novice and still have much ground to cover before I'm comfortable manipulating data.  There is one method I would like to include along with your answer and that is removing duplicates of entries to the array by using uniq!  Please see below for my final code block.  What I plan to do is use this function as a header for an erb template.

Answer (score 0):

@Thilo, apparently the comment section did not allow me to show the code modifications.  As previously mentioned the uniq! method removes any duplicated element from the array.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

```
require 'csv'

module AlertHash
  @alert_hash = {}
  CSV.foreach("../data.csv") do |row|
    report, number = row
    next if number == "Number"
    @alert_hash[number] ||= [] # initialize array if required
    @alert_hash[number] << report # add value
  end

  def self.report(number)
    @alert_hash[number].uniq!.join(", ") # concatenate reports to @alert_hash array
  end
end

puts "Alert: " + AlertHash.report("12345678")
# OUTPUT => Alert: INC AMT %, OUT AMT %
```